# Call one Gradle Task from another with arguments

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I have a gradle task which calls a script and passed the command line arguments to the script using `-PARGS`.

```
task taskAll(type: Exec, dependsOn: taskinit) {
    environment['PROJECT_ROOT'] = "${projectDir}"
    workingDir rootProject.projectDir.path
    description = 'Main task'

    executable rootProject.projectDir.path + "/execute.me"
    if (project.hasProperty('ARGS')) {
        args(ARGS.split(','))
    }
}
```

I call this gradle task with any of the below options

```
./gradlew taskAll
./gradlew taskAll -PARGS="arg1"
./gradlew taskAll -PARGS="arg2"
```

However, am looking to see if I split taskAll into multiple tasks, say

```
./gradlew taskA    #Calls task taskAll with arg1
./gradlew taskB    #Calls task taskAll with arg2
```

I understand that I will have to replicate the taskAll to create `taskA`, `taskB` and remove the "if" condition and hardcode args in each of these.

However, I wonder if it is possible to have a cleaner implementation by having MainTask which only calls the executable, and then have `TaskA`, `TaskB`, `TaskC` call `MainTask` and pass the arguments `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In most cases, executing one task from another is done by configuration of task dependencies, via providing `dependsOn` and optionally `mustRunAfter` properies. In your case, it's not possible to use it, since your main task has to be executed after some configuration task. In that case, you can use `finalizedBy` property of the task.

For your requirements, you can create a number of tasks, which will set some script variable with predefined arguments, just as you need it. And you could leave your main task, which will call something, relying on this arguments. Only thing you need to do, is to make each custom task finilizedBy your main task. So, every call of custom task will execute the main task after excution.

Here is the short example, how to do it:

```
//define a variable to store arguments
def ARGS = null

//2 custom tasks, which set arguments during the execution phase
task taskA << {
    ARGS = "poperty1,property2"
}

task taskB << {
    ARGS = "property3,property4"
}

//your main task
task mainTask (type: Exec) {
    environment['PROJECT_ROOT'] = "${projectDir}"
    workingDir rootProject.projectDir.path
    description = 'Main task'

    executable rootProject.projectDir.path + "/execute.me"

    //here is the main difference, we moved arguments setting into 
    //execution phase, before execution of this task
    doFirst{
        //if you call custom task it will be executed with predefined params
        if (ARGS != null) {
            args(ARGS)
        //if you call mainTask, you are able to pass arguments via command line with -PCOMMAND_LINE_ARGS=123
        } else if (project.hasProperty('COMMAND_LINE_ARGS')) {
            args(COMMAND_LINE_ARGS)
        } else {
            throw new GradleException("No arguments found")
        }
    }
}

//finilization settings for custom tasks
taskA.finalizedBy mainTask
taskB.finalizedBy mainTask
```

Comment: *There is no native support for calling execution of one task from another in gradle*, moreover it's highly discouraged!

Comment: @Opal you mean, it's possible to use costomeTask.execute()?

Comment: Yes, sure. Why not? You can call execute on other task. [This](https://gist.github.com/Opalo/e92101a0bc3e30821d29) is perfectly valid gradle script.

Comment: @Opal Yes, maybe I was wrong with formulation. But as I know, it's not a advisable way to do it, if you can do it via tasks dependecies.

Comment: Of, course it's not. That's what I wrote in my first comment :)

Answer (score 5):

A prettier way to do that with [GradleBuild API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/GradleBuild.html):

```
    task ('taskA', type: GradleBuild) {
        startParameter.projectProperties = ['ARGS':'arg1']
        tasks = ['taskAll']
    }
    
    task ('taskB', type: GradleBuild) {
        startParameter.projectProperties = ['ARGS':'arg2']
        tasks = ['taskAll']
    }
```

You can have complex project properties, for example command line argument `-Pmyextension.config=true` will become :

```
startParameter.projectProperties = ['myextension.config':true]
```

Note that this will erase CLI args. If you need to append it :

```
startParameter.projectProperties << project.getGradle().getStartParameter().getProjectProperties() << ['myextension.config':true]
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. Maybe you can help me? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70993675/4167198

Answer (score 0):

You can use ext:

```
task outraTask << {
    printf(arg0)
    printf(arg1)
}

project(':projetc2').tasks.outraTask {
    ext.arg0 = "0"
    ext.arg1 = "1"
}.execute()
```

output:

```
> Task :projetc2:outraTask
0
1
```