# Passing parameters to dependable task of custom task

Tags: gradle, plugins

There is task which can be executed with parameter like this:

```sh
./gradlew taskX -Pkey=value
```

And plugin with custom task which should execute `taskX`:

```kotlin
class CustomPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.tasks.register("custom", CustomTask::class.java)
            .configure {
                it.description = "Description"
                it.group = "Group"

                val taskX = project.getTasksByName("taskX", true).first()

                it.dependsOn(taskX)
            }
    }
}
```

I would expect something like this for example:

```kotlin
it.dependsOn(taskX, "key=value")
```

How to pass parameters to `dependsOn`?

Comment: Maybe a more recent answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69587149/2700582

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple answer: You can't.** Task dependencies only express **what** needs to be done beforehand, **not how** it needs to be done.

---

Let me show you a simple example, why something like this is not possible in the Gradle task system:

First, we need to know that in Gradle, every task will be executed only **once** in a single invocation (often called build). Now imagine a task that needs to be run before two tasks that are unrelated to each other. A good real world example is the task `compileJava` from the [Java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_tasks) that both the `test` task and the `jar` task depend on. If `dependsOn` would support parameters, it could happen that two tasks depend on a single task with different parameters. What parameters should be used in this case?

As a solution, you may configure the other task directly in your plugin. If you want to pass the parameter only if your custom task is run, you may need to add another task that runs as a setup and applies the required configuration to the actual task:

```
task setup {
    doFirst {
        // apply configuration
    }
}

taskX.mustRunAfter setup

task custom {
    dependsOn setup
    dependsOn taskX
}
```

This example uses Groovy, but it should be possible to translate it to Kotlin and use it in your plugin.

---

**Edit regarding actual parameter**

To be honest, I am not that familiar with the Android Gradle plugin, but if I get [this documentation](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig:testInstrumentationRunnerArguments) right, the project property `android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.annotation` is just an alternative to using the following code in the build script:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunnerArgument 'annotation', '<some-value>'
    }
}
```

You may try to define the following task and then run it using `./gradlew customTest`

```
task customTest {
    doFirst {
        android.defaultConfig.testInstrumentationRunnerArgument 'annotation', '<some-value>'
    }
    finalizedBy 'connectedAndroidTest'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But I still wonder how `-P` can be set in `doFirst` then. As I understand such kind of parameters are assigned to the project, but `project.setProperty` doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Project properties (the ones passed via `-P`) are just a way to keep a parameter or configuration out of the build script. But since you want to apply your configuration in a plugin, there is no need to use a project property at all. What is the type of task `taskX` in your example?

Comment: It is `connectedAndroidTest`. Property is `android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.annotation`, it sets annotation which should be used by runner to run particular tests and ignore others. So it means that I need find proper configuration in `project.configurations` and set this property?

Comment: I edited my answer with focus on your task and property.

Comment: Thanks. Found also how to do it with Kotlin. Unfortunately by some reason setting `testInstrumentationRunnerArgument` doesn't make any difference. It seems like `android` extension uses this property earlier somehow. Will ask another question.