# How to pass external variables to a CORB module from within the ml-gradle execution?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-corb

Is there a way to pass parameters into CORB modules from ml-gradle without passing them on the command line via `-DPROCESS_MODULE.parameter`. I have a CorbTask that I plan to call a few times from another Task with different options each time.

Comment: Does this answer can help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69587149/2700582

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a generic way for the CoRB task to define and make available custom inputs as project properties, as it does for the standard CoRB options.

You can set the custom inputs in an options file, and then specify the [**OPTIONS-FILE**](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#OPTIONS-FILE).

Comment: Thanks Mads.. I will attempt the OPTIONS-FILE route.