# Run Gradle task with command line parameters several times from Groovy script

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, gradlew, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am working on an Android project which uses a Gradle task with command line parameters. The task should be called from command line like that:
`gradlew myTask -Parg1=aaa`

Instead of calling it from command line I want to call this task from a Gradle file where I have all the arguments in a list. I need to create another task which runs `myTask` in a loop with all the arguments. By following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69587149/4167198) example I created the following code:

```
def data=['1', '2', '3']
project.task('runAll') {
    data.collect { count ->
        project.task('run_' + count, type: GradleBuild) {
            startParameter.projectProperties = ['arg1': count]
            tasks = ['myTask']
        }.name
    }.forEach { name ->
        dependsOn name
    }
}
```

When running individual tasks `run_1`, `run_2`, and `run_3` everything works fine. If I run `runAll`, `run_1` finishes successfully, but `run_2` and `run_3` crashes with the following error:

`Included build C:\Projects\MyAwesomeApp\app has build path :app which is the same as included build C:\Projects\MyAwesomeApp\app`

Can you help me solve this error?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by running a task multiple times with different parameters? What version of Gradle are you using? Does [setting `buildName` help](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12872)?

Comment: The problem looks to be in `dependsOn name` which may depends on itself. Maybe you should debug this and share more info ? Or I suggest you to create your tasks and then create a `runAll` task with GradleBuild API that call an array of your tasks... not a dependency...